# Getting comfortable with GTO?

Tags: texas-hold-em, psychology, gto

I've been studying GTO and such after years of playing without any formal training.  I just at the point where I feel like I've learned enough to be dangerous, and am trying to apply my studies to live game play.  A general issue I struggle with is to play through uncomfortable situations when I've learned that I should do so.

GTO and pro play seem to basically take the stance that just about any situation can be won and should be fought for.  I get how the theory would support these situations, but they tend to be unintuitive and uncomfortable spots to play.  I wonder how much my game will suffer if I avoid these situations.  If I should definitely play these, can anyone maybe suggest a way to look at these situations that will make them more comfortable?

Here's an example, a [Quiz from pokercoaching.com](https://pokercoaching.com/quizzes/quiz-1972/):

[image]

So the pro presenting this hand comes in for 2bb, noting that he would fold to a shove, and gets called by the BB.

We wiff the flop, and this is where I struggle. When this flop comes, I question my decisions to not fold pre flop, and I really just want to dump this hand.  I figure I could be drawing nearly dead against a Q or a pocket pair, and what am I really hoping will happen here?  Do I expect that I'm going to win this with a bluff most of the time?  Why is this hand worth more of my chips?

How much will my game/WR suffer if I fold in situations like this.  Is it a crime to not play this hand through? How much of being a top tier player involves being able to make the best of situations like this?